# How to modify the behavior of all rules at once, in ANTLR4?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

This is my grammar:

```
foo returns [Alpha ret]
    :
    { Alpha a = new Alpha(); }
    /* something specific for the rule foo */
    { $ret = a; }
    ;
```

I have 10 grammar rules, which look exactly the same. The only differences between them are located in the "something specific" line. How do I avoid rewriting this code over and over again and somehow share this `Alpha` instantiating and returning behavior between all my rules?

Comment: This looks like a synthesized attribute. If it is not directly used on a semantic predicate, you should consider moving all this code to a listener. You gain target independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without merging various parser rules into one, AFAIK:

```
merged returns [Alpha ret]
 : { Alpha a = new Alpha(); }
   ( foo /* something specific for the rule foo */
   | bar /* something specific for the rule bar */
   | mu  /* something specific for the rule mu  */
   )
   { $ret = a; }
 ;
```

Parser rules are converted to plain methods in the particular ANTLR runtime you're targeting. So, in your case, if there's no nice way to do it in Java, then there's no way to do it in the grammar.

As a side note: have you considered moving the code from the grammar into a listener or visitor? In my opinion, separating grammar from target specific code often leads to less bugs, and better and more easily tested code.

Comment: You are right, it's time to move Java code away from the grammar! Great advice.